# Capitalize AM/PM in Material 3 Jetpack Compose TimePicker

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, timepicker, android-timepicker, android-jetpack-compose-material3

How to capitalize the AM/PM in Jetpack Compose M3 TimePicker?

Missed to add earlier - Works in my emulator, the issue is device-specific (depends on `Locale`).

In the emulator, the AM/PM appears in capital letters, but in a physical device the letters appear in small letters

Code is directly copied from [Android Docs for TimePicker](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/compose/material3/package-summary#TimePicker(androidx.compose.material3.TimePickerState,androidx.compose.ui.Modifier,androidx.compose.material3.TimePickerColors,androidx.compose.material3.TimePickerLayoutType)) and [Android Source code for TimePickerDialog](https://cs.android.com/androidx/platform/tools/dokka-devsite-plugin/+/master:testData/compose/samples/material3/samples/TimePickerSamples.kt;l=230;drc=03ca30d22e6ee3483142f2e4048db459cb5afb79),

Physical Device specs,
Model - Redmi 8
Android OS - 10
MIUI 12.5.2

Emulator
Pixel 2 API 31

[image]

I raised this issue in Google Tracker,
https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/295761434.
https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/295971939

But, on the same device, the Google Clock app has caps AM/PM.

[image]

Comment: can you share the code you have tried? because it's working fine in my example as well.

Comment: which locale you used in your phone. because it work fine in my galaxy note 10 lite android 13

Comment: I can see the local is - `en-IN`.

Comment: I have changed my phone Locale to en-IN its working. Try app on other device

Comment: I have a Redmi Note 10 Pro which also has the issue.

Comment: Try on other OEM like samsung, vivo, oppo,realme

Comment: Do you use compose BOM?

Comment: Unfortunately, I have only Xiaomi devices and emulators to test. For code details, repo link - https://github.com/Abhimanyu14/finance-manager. I am not using Compose BOM.

Comment: Let me check the code

Comment: But isn't the point exactly that the texts used *should* depend on locale?

Comment: Google Clock does not depend on the locale. I am checking on the same device.

Comment: how did you added keyboard? or did you make custom solution?

Answer (score 0):

This is my code which is working fine. You can try this one.

**Preview**

[image: example]

```
import androidx.compose.foundation.background
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.Box
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.Column
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.IntrinsicSize
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.Row
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.Spacer
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.fillMaxWidth
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.height
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.padding
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.width
import androidx.compose.material3.Button
import androidx.compose.material3.ExperimentalMaterial3Api
import androidx.compose.material3.MaterialTheme
import androidx.compose.material3.SnackbarHost
import androidx.compose.material3.SnackbarHostState
import androidx.compose.material3.Surface
import androidx.compose.material3.Text
import androidx.compose.material3.TextButton
import androidx.compose.material3.TimePicker
import androidx.compose.material3.rememberTimePickerState
import androidx.compose.runtime.Composable
import androidx.compose.runtime.getValue
import androidx.compose.runtime.mutableStateOf
import androidx.compose.runtime.remember
import androidx.compose.runtime.rememberCoroutineScope
import androidx.compose.runtime.setValue
import androidx.compose.ui.Alignment
import androidx.compose.ui.Modifier
import androidx.compose.ui.unit.dp
import androidx.compose.ui.window.Dialog
import androidx.compose.ui.window.DialogProperties
import kotlinx.coroutines.launch
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat
import java.util.Calendar
import java.util.Locale


@OptIn(ExperimentalMaterial3Api::class)
@Composable
fun Ex10() {

    var showTimePicker by remember { mutableStateOf(false) }
    val state = rememberTimePickerState()
    val formatter = remember { SimpleDateFormat("hh:mm a", Locale.getDefault()) }
    val snackState = remember { SnackbarHostState() }
    val snackScope = rememberCoroutineScope()

    Box(propagateMinConstraints = false) {
        Button(
            modifier = Modifier.align(Alignment.Center),
            onClick = { showTimePicker = true }
        ) {
            Text("Set Time")
        }
        SnackbarHost(hostState = snackState)
    }

    if (showTimePicker) {
        TimePickerDialog(
            onCancel = { showTimePicker = false },
            onConfirm = {
                val cal = Calendar.getInstance()
                cal.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, state.hour)
                cal.set(Calendar.MINUTE, state.minute)
                cal.isLenient = false
                snackScope.launch {
                    snackState.showSnackbar("Entered time: ${formatter.format(cal.time)}")
                }
                showTimePicker = false
            },
        ) {
            TimePicker(state = state)
        }
    }
}


@Composable
fun TimePickerDialog(
    title: String = "Select Time",
    onCancel: () -> Unit,
    onConfirm: () -> Unit,
    toggle: @Composable () -> Unit = {},
    content: @Composable () -> Unit,
) {
    Dialog(
        onDismissRequest = onCancel,
        properties = DialogProperties(
            usePlatformDefaultWidth = false
        ),
    ) {
        Surface(
            shape = MaterialTheme.shapes.extraLarge,
            tonalElevation = 6.dp,
            modifier = Modifier
                .width(IntrinsicSize.Min)
                .height(IntrinsicSize.Min)
                .background(
                    shape = MaterialTheme.shapes.extraLarge,
                    color = MaterialTheme.colorScheme.surface
                ),
        ) {
            toggle()
            Column(
                modifier = Modifier.padding(24.dp),
                horizontalAlignment = Alignment.CenterHorizontally
            ) {
                Text(
                    modifier = Modifier
                        .fillMaxWidth()
                        .padding(bottom = 20.dp),
                    text = title,
                    style = MaterialTheme.typography.labelMedium
                )
                content()
                Row(
                    modifier = Modifier
                        .height(40.dp)
                        .fillMaxWidth()
                ) {
                    Spacer(modifier = Modifier.weight(1f))
                    TextButton(
                        onClick = onCancel
                    ) { Text("Cancel") }
                    TextButton(
                        onClick = onConfirm
                    ) { Text("OK") }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```